# Hamcrest matcher closeTo not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, rest, integration-testing, spock

I'm performing some integration tests on a rest service using Spock and RestAssured. I'm having trouble checking the double values with hamcrest's `closeTo` matcher:

```
class PlaceITSpec extends Specification {
 def "Create a Place"() {
    given:
        def place = ['name' : 'Depot A',
                    'location': [
                            'latitude': 40d,
                            'longitude': -3d
                    ]]
        def request = given().accept(ContentType.JSON).contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(place)

    when: "POST /places"
        def response = request.with().post("http://localhost:8080/places")

    then: "I get a the created place resource and 201 status code"
        response.then().log().all()
                .statusCode(201)
                .body("name", equalTo(place['name']))
                .body("location.longitude", is(closeTo(place['location']['longitude'], 0.000001d)))
                .body("location.latitude", is(closeTo(place['location']['latitude'], 0.000001d)))
                .body("_links.self", notNullValue())
                .body("_links.place", notNullValue())

  }
}
```

The test fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path location.longitude doesn't match.
Expected: is a numeric value within <1.0E-6> of <-3.0>
  Actual: -3.0
```

Everything seems ok. Trying to discard obvious errors I have used a error value of 1. Yet the tests fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path location.longitude doesn't match.
Expected: is a numeric value within <1.0> of <-3.0>
  Actual: -3.0
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong. Any one suffered the same issue?

Comment: Are you comparing a string to a number?

Comment: Nope, I'm comparing two doubles. Or at least that's the intent. Let's check.

Comment: Checked! I wasn't comparing a string to a number. RestAssured is making the right transformations for you. In any case, this made me find the right documentation. For the equality check to work, instead of using doubles `-3d` you must compare using float `-3f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the right answer through [RestAssured doc](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#note-on-floats-and-doubles)

> Floating point numbers must be compared with a Java "float" primitive

I updated my code to:

```
class PlaceITSpec extends Specification {
def "Create a Place"() {
given:
    def place = ['name' : 'Depot A',
                'location': [
                        'latitude': 40f,
                        'longitude': -3f
                ]]
    def request = given().accept(ContentType.JSON).contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(place)

when: "POST /places"
    def response = request.with().post("http://localhost:8080/places")

then: "I get a the created place resource and 201 status code"
    response.then().log().all()
            .statusCode(201)
            .body("name", equalTo(place['name']))
            .body("location.longitude", equalTo(place['location']['longitude']))
            .body("location.latitude", equalTo(place['location']['latitude']))
            .body("_links.self", notNullValue())
            .body("_links.place", notNullValue())

  }
}
```

Check that latitude and longitude values now have the `f` suffix to indicate `float` primitive isntead of `double` primitive. And also changed the `is(closeTo(data,error))` to `equalTo(data)`